# Specifying Hierarchy in REST APIs

Tags: json, api, rest

Yes I know there is no hard and fast rule and yes I have read other stack posts on this.

Given this example I have a few ways I think this could be done.  What I'm looking for are any other ideas or ways people have specified hierarchies.

I like to identify the resource by value as much as possible FIRST in the uri.  For example I don't like putting everything into the querystring, it's just my pref:

`/cars/10/colors/2` - a common convention

-or-

`/cars/10?colors=2` - another common convention

I prefer finding the resource first and identifying it then add filtering in the querystring.  This is filtering that is not based on matching by IDs or names, but stuff you would lets say want to add to a query such as greaterThan, sorting, etc.

With that, I'm wondering if people are also finding success doing it this way.  Now here is where it gets complicated.  I want to dig down into properties of properties.

Lets say we have the following resources and relationships defined in our API:

**Cars**
(these are the entities in our code we send back and expect in requests/responses.  Obviously a GET wouldn't have objects)

```
{
   id:null,
   colors: null,
   year: null,
   engines: null
}
```

colors would be an array of json color objects when populated
engines would e an array of engine json objects when populated

So those are a couple of relationships that Car has.

**Color**

```
{
    name: null,
    tone: null
}
```

**engine**

```
{
     name: null,
     horsepower: null,
}
```

Now lets say I want to allow our users to really specify some more complex filtering but at the 2nd level.  How are you doing that?

A couple ways I can think of:

```
/cars/10/engines.horespower:v4?[and then some other filtering or actions added here like sorting, limiting, paging, etc...]
```

or here's another example like that: `/people/locations.cities.id:124?`...

so a person json object has a locations property.  A locations json object has an id property..that's how I'm thinking about this example/scenario.

I do not want to be doing things like this:

```
/cars/engines?name=c5000
```

This breaks REST convention because I am not actually specifying a heirarchy here.  You might think you are but what this is really saying is...I want engines back not cars with this kind of url because engines is the last resource type in the url.  And there are no params specified in that URI this time...whereas last time we had `/cars/10/engines.horespower:v4` and that DOES imply a heirarchy because Im using a period to specify a sub property of engines AND because I'm setting it to a value so that part of the uri becomes a param now.

I'm sure you can figure out another way for users to filter by getting to sub properties of the resource you want back but then you have to figure out how, it's not an easy task because you want to make sure the pattern you come up with is extensible and reusable for any object in terms of how the users specify queries, paging, and more importantly for me in this situation, getting at nested properties and acting on them.

Ideas?  Experiences?  Thoughts?

Comment: I would try RQL if I were you: https://github.com/persvr/rql there are other already existing query languages too. The only problem that they are not standard. Don't try to reinvent the wheel and please try to avoid topic duplication and reopening. I saw the same question yesterday...

Comment: @inf3rno, could you please provide other examples?

Comment: @Opal http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/

Comment: Didn't know about odata, great! Thanks!

Comment: @Opal Most of the databases have a REST API, so I would try them too.

Comment: Do you know any other resources worth investigation?

Comment: @Opal Not really. Mongodb has for example a REST interface: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/ . Btw. I was talking about is general querying. So if you can describe the URI structure with URI templates, then you don't need a standard query language.

Comment: Added an answer here to this kind of questions. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33170477/607033 I hope this will stop people from asking the same question every day.

Comment: Great, thank you very much!